# SQL query sailors

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Sailor (SID, Sname, Age)  
Boat (BID, Bname, Color)  
Reserve (SID, BID, Day) ------
```

With this schema how would it be possible to

Find all sailors names who have reserved only green boats

I can only managed to get all sailors who have reserved green boats

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt(s).

Answer (score 1):

In this query, I have selected all those sailors who have reserved boats other than 'green'. They might have taken green also but their SID will get captured in the 'in' query. Outer query (Outside in) will exclude and give Sailors who have reserved only green boats through 'not in' statement in 'where' clause.

You could use left join also to do the same instead of a 'not in' clause but i prefer 'not in' over 'left join' as this will be much more efficient than 'left join' specially in case of large tables

Try this:-

```
Select a.SID,a.Sname,a.Age
from
Sailor a
inner join
Reserve b
on a.SID=b.SID
inner join
Boat c
on b.BID=c.BID
where c.Color='green'
and a.SID not in
(
Select a.SID
from
Sailor a
inner join
Reserve b
on a.SID=b.SID
inner join
Boat c
on b.BID=c.BID
where c.Color <> 'green'
) ;
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Left justified SQL, so hard to read...

Comment: This is great thank you so much, is there a way to do this query without making the joins explicit?

Comment: You can put every table names in the 'From Clause' with commas without explicitly writing 'join' and on statement in 'Where Clause' without explicitly writing 'on'. By default the join will be inner join

Answer (score 1):

One another way:

```
select Sailor.* from Boat 
inner join 
(
     select Reserve.sid, Reserve.bid from Reserve
     inner join (select SID from Reserve group by SID having count(distinct BID) = 1) t
     on Reserve.SID = t.SID
) tt
on Boat.bid = tt.bid
inner join Sailor
on Sailor.sid = tt.sid
where
Boat.color = 'green'
```

Well, "tt" subquery contains only those rows (SID and BID) from `Reserve` table, where SID's have only one unique BID. So, if SID have reserved 2 or more different BID's, these rows are ignored.

Then we  join this to `Boat` table and using filter `where Boat.color = 'green'` we only get those rows,  which Boat's color is green.

If in `Reserve` table, one SID have unique BID's, then you can remove `distinct` keyword from query

Comment: This is amazing thank you it works, could you please tell me the thinking behind this query? and when faced with a problem like "only" how would you tackle it? Thank you so much

Comment: for example without explicitly mentioning the word join

Comment: @helpmewithjava - I will add little explanation, but what you mean: `without explicitly mentioning the word join`? Do you mean old join style? which uses commas ? or something else ?

Comment: Sorry yes, one which uses commas and doesn't mention the word join however has joins implicit such as sailors.sid = reserves.sid

Comment: @helpmewithjava - added little explanation, I'm sorry for my english,  hope you will understood content.

Comment: @helpmewithjava - About comma join style, this is old, deprecated and not recommended anymore, better to use explicit joins. Really, personally for me, explicit join's are more readable and intuitive, then old comma style.

Comment: You are a legend man thank you so much for the explanation I understand it now thank you

Comment: @helpmewithjava - You are welcome